# Vectorized version of `__contains__` (contained in) in pandas/numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame([["x", "y", "z"], ["y", "x", "z"]])
valid = ("x", "y")

print(a in valid)  # Doesn't work
```

I want the output to be:

```
      0     1      2
0  True  True  False
1  True  True  False
```

`np.logical_or.reduce` can do this but the result is not a dataframe (or series) but rather a raw numpy array:

```py
np.logical_or.reduce(a == v for v in valid)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: you want the output to be a list of lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `isin` method: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

This produces the desired data as the correct type:

```py
a.isin(valid)
# [[True, True, False], [True, True, False]]
```